# Cassandra db user's password complexity

Tags: cassandra

How can we customize password complexity in Cassandra for database users ?
Like the password must contains 9 character ,2 special character ,1 upper case ,1 lower case etc.

Comment: This question needs a little bit more context, in which interface are users setting their password?

Comment: DBA will set password in Cassandra database it self for other users .

Comment: Creating a new password authenticator is incredibly simple and it is pluggable if your ok with building a jar and putting it in the lib directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Cassandra. Usually this is a responsibility of external authentication system, that is integrated via [DSE's Unified Authentication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/secConfigAuthTOC.html), or recently open sourced [LDAPAuthenticator](https://www.instaclustr.com/apache-cassandra-ldap-authentication/).